# Scanner in Java not working

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to write a very simple number guessing game (code is below). After 1 round is finished, the user is supposed to be able to decide whether he/she wants to play another round or not. Problem is, the program always skips the last question (never letting the user answer 'y' or otherwise. What am I missing here? Is there something about `java.util.Scanner` I don't know about?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessNum {

public GuessNum() {         

        int numRandom = 0;    
        int numGuess;    
        int life = 5;    
        String want = "";    
        Random rand = new Random();    
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            int lifeLeft = 5;
            numRandom = rand.nextInt(9)+1;

            System.out.print("\nGuess the Number [1..10]\n");
            System.out.print("===================\n");
            System.out.print("You have " + lifeLeft + " chances.\n");

            do {
                do {
                    System.out.print("What number do I have in mind: ");
                    numGuess = scan.nextInt();

                    if (numGuess < 1 || numGuess > 10)    
                        System.out.println("Invalid input. Range is 1-10.");    
                } while (numGuess < 1 || numGuess > 10);

                if (numGuess != numRandom && lifeLeft != 0)
                    System.out.println("Wrong! You only have " + --lifeLeft + " chances left.");

            } while (numGuess!=numRandom && lifeLeft > 0);

            if (numGuess == numRandom)
                System.out.println("Correct! -- in " + (life - lifeLeft) + " guess(es).");

            if (lifeLeft == 0) {
                System.out.println("You have no more lives..");
                System.out.println("This is the number: " + numRandom);
            }

            System.out.print("\nEnter 'y' if you want to play again or any other character to exit: ");
                want = scan.nextLine();
        } while (want.equals("y") || want.equals("Y"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        new GuessNum();
    }
}
```

Comment: After a decade of complaints about how difficult it is to simply fetch a bit of input from the console, Sun gave us the `Scanner` class so "Beginning Java" texts could write succinct examples. But `Scanner` is far from foolproof. I usually take the trouble to explicitly read and scan lines via `BufferedReader` etc.

Comment: For more on using `Scanner` and validating input (e.g. integers, vowels-only, etc), see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059333/validating-input-using-java-util-scanner/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `want = scan.next();` instead of `nextLine()`.

The reason for your problem is that following the preceding `nextInt()`, you're still on the same line, and `nextLine()` returns the rest of the current line.

Here's a smallest snippet to reproduce the behavior:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("nextInt() = " + sc.nextInt());
System.out.println("nextLine() = " + sc.nextLine());
```

When you type in, say, `5` and then hit *Enter*, the output is:

```
nextInt() = 5
nextLine() =
```

That is, `nextLine()` did not block for your input, because the current line still has an empty string remaining.

For comparison, when you type in, say `5 yeah!` and then hit *Enter*, then the output is:

```
nextInt() = 5
nextLine() =  yeah!
```

Note that `" yeah!"` actually comes from the same line as the `5`. This is exactly as specified in the documentation:

> [`String nextLine()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29): Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. *This method returns the rest of the current line*, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.

---

#### On half-open ranges

Assuming that the number to guess is between 1 and 10 inclusive, the following code is "wrong":

```
numRandom = rand.nextInt(9)+1; // this can only be in 1..9 range inclusive!
```

Here's an excerpt from the documentation of `java.util.Random`:

> [`int nextInt(int n)`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29): Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)

That is, like a lot of methods in Java's API, `Random.nextInt(int)` uses the half-open range, with inclusive lower bound and exclusive upper bound.

#### Related questions

- [Are upper bounds of indexed ranges always assumed to be exclusive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440282/are-upper-bounds-of-indexed-ranges-always-assumed-to-be-exclusive)

Comment: Ah, thanks (for the random generator correction, too)! I thought nextLine() starts by default at a new line. Should pay more attention to the documentation next time.

Answer (score 3):

Use `scan.next()+ scan.nextLine();` instead
  eg.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

String s = scan.nextLine() +scan.nextLine();
```

Problem occurs because the last newline character for the last line of input is still queued in the input buffer and the next `nextLine()` will be reading the remainder of the line (which is empty).
So, when you use next it goes to the next token, then you can get the remaining input using `nextLine()`

Comment: why not `scan.nextLine()`?

Comment: Thanks it worked!     and why scan.nextLine() + scan.nextLine();      it is simply because my case was same, as I was getting the output as  empty String instead of a Bunch of Words/String,        and doing so took the initial empty String and concatenated it with the actual String.