# Get the next string, according to its natural ordering

Tags: java, string

In Java, the  class String implements Comparable, which means there's a total ordering on the String objects. This ordering is referred to as the class's *natural ordering*, and the class's `compareTo` method is referred to as its natural comparison method. The set of String objects is also countable in the mathematical sense.

I need a function that takes a String and returns the next one according to String's natural ordering.

For the mathematically inclined,

```
function(X) = Y, where Y is such that: 1) X < Y
                                       2) for all Z, if X < Z, then Y <= Z.
```

Can you think of a function that does this for Strings? (Those matching `^[A-Za-z0-9]+$`. I don't care, but you can avoid the control characters or anything that might cause headaches with encodings, is illegal in XML, has line breaks, or similar "problematic" characters.)

Comment: Is "A" < "AA" < "AB" in your natural order?

Comment: `@gawi:` It's not _my_ natural order; String implements Comparable: [String's `compareTo`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29)... It's lexicographic.

Comment: Then I believe the answer of meriton is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String successor(String s) {
    return s + '\0';
}
```

Or with your limited alphabet:

```
String successor(String s) {
    return s + '0';
}
```

since '0' has the smallest unicode value of all legal characters.

Why you would need this is anyone's guess, though ... probably there is a less hacky solution.

Comment: "Test" < "TestA", but "Tesz" < "TestA" so this isn't the solution.

Comment: `@gawi:` It's not homework, it's just a hack. I have a binary search that returns the index of the first record; rather than write one that returns the index of the last record, I'm just gonna find the first record of the _next_ string.

Comment: "Tesz".compareTo("TestA") returns 6, so "Tesz" > "TestA".

Answer (score 1):

As first pointed out by the other answer, the successor of a string is that string immediately followed by the `char` whose value is `0` (in Java, `char` is an *unsigned* integral value, `[0,65535]` ([§4.2.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2.1))).

```
// returns the lexicographical successor of a string
public static String successor(String s) {
    return s + "\0";
}
```

The following excerpt from [`SortedSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) documentation prescribes this exact idiom for `String`, and gives a motivation *WHY* you'd want to use a successor method like this:

> Note: several methods return subsets with restricted ranges. Such ranges are *half-open*, that is, they include their low endpoint but not their high endpoint (where applicable). If you need a *closed range* (which includes both endpoints), and the element type allows for calculation of the successor of a given value, merely request the subrange from `lowEndpoint` to `successor(highEndpoint)`. For example, suppose that `s` is a sorted set of strings. The following idiom obtains a view containing all of the strings in `s` from `low` to `high`, inclusive:
>
> ```
> SortedSet<String> sub = s.subSet(low, high+"\0");
> ```
>
> A similar technique can be used to generate an *open range* (which contains neither endpoint). The following idiom obtains a view containing all of the strings in `s` from `low` to `high`, exclusive:
>
> ```
> SortedSet<String> sub = s.subSet(low+"\0", high);
> ```

Note that this idiom is still awkward to use nonetheless, and it may not always be easy to compute the successor for any generic type (e.g. if it's just a `SortedSet<Number>`). A much more refined API is [`NavigableSet<E>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html), which `extends SortedSet<E>` and defines these range operations to allow any combination of open or close end points using `boolean` flags.

#### Related questions

- [Inclusive range queries when only half-open range is supported? (ala `SortedMap.subMap`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857680/how-to-do-inclusive-range-queries-when-only-half-open-range-is-supported-ala-sor)
- [Is it possible to write a generic +1 method for numeric box types in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834522/is-it-possible-to-write-a-generic-1-method-for-numeric-box-types-in-java)
- [Are upper bounds of indexed ranges always assumed to be exclusive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440282/are-upper-bounds-of-indexed-ranges-always-assumed-to-be-exclusive)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would need something like that... bruteforcing something?
anyway here is a very primitive solution:

```
public static String getNextString(String input)
{
  if(input == null || input.trim().length() < 1)
  {
    return("0");
  }
  else
  {
    String trimmed = input.trim();
    int lastPos = input.length()-1;
    int last = (int) input.charAt(lastPos);
    last++;
    if(last > (int) 'z')
    {
      if(lastPos == 0)
      {
        return "00";
      }
      else
      {
        return getNextString(trimmed.substring(0,lastPos-1)) + "0";
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Obviously, there might be bugs cuz i just typed this from my mobile phone on my way home...